# Comparison of Open Source Desktop GIS Packages

Tags: open-source-gis, comparison, desktop-gis

I'm curious as to what comparisons are out there between different Open Source Desktop GIS software packages. I'm aware that there has been a [QGIS and gvSIG comparison](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/qgis-and-gvsig-comparison) on this site but I am looking for comparisons between any OpenSource Desktop GIS.

A substantial list of Open Source GIS software can be found in response to the question: [What are some Free and Open Source GIS Desktop packages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-are-some-free-and-open-source-gis-desktop-packages)

I don't expect a single comparison with everything in it, but comparative subsets. Also any comprehensive benchmark/testing that may have been performed between any grouping of these products.

Comment: What's the purpose of your research? Do you have a question you are trying to answer about open source GIS? Research without a question is a bit useless...

Comment: Some of your data is very hard to measure (easy to use). We also can't prioritize your list (I only need English, so any other language is moot)

Comment: The most important components of GIS softwares are spatial analysis methods - It should be number 1 in your list.

Comment: Is there a more recent (2019) comparison - the one linked to by markusN is very out of date (QGIS 1.3 vs QGIS 3.8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen, this is the most exhaustive comparison matrix of GIS software out there:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Albk_XRkhVkzdGxyYk8tNEZvLUp1UTUzTFN5bjlLX2c&hl=en#gid=0

There are quite a lot of variables in this matrix, some which may be out of scope for your current study, but the issue of application scalability can be drawn from such a topic.

Other links
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_geographic_information_systems_software

Comment: More recent version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nNEtjWBROepTzGgTjZ8PslWyv7z_QqzgF1uRSm-0at0/edit?usp=sharing&authkey=CPGQ26EG

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice matrix (table) about "Matrix on OSGeo and COTS (Commercial off-the-shelf) software functionality", see this online [spreadsheet](http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Albk_XRkhVkzdGxyYk8tNEZvLUp1UTUzTFN5bjlLX2c&hl=en).
The effort of compiling the table was led by Tom McConnell, various project leads contributed to it.

Comment: I like that. Who created it?

Comment: I have expanded my answer (and was involved myself).

Comment: Very extensive. It's obvious that a lot of effort has been put into compiling this table. I've only checked GRASS and QGIS columns so far, but unfortunately QGIS information is rather outdated (v 1.3).

Comment: I agree, such tables need to be continuously updated. Perhaps contact Cameron Shorter to obtain write access?

Comment: More recent version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nNEtjWBROepTzGgTjZ8PslWyv7z_QqzgF1uRSm-0at0/edit?usp=sharing&authkey=CPGQ26EG

Answer (score 6):

I've now done a little searching myself on this and there seem to have been a few academic papers published with comparisons. Even the newest one is a year+ old now, but they do make for some interesting reading.

- [An overview on current free and open source desktop GIS developments (PDF)](http://terragis.net/docs/presentations/sstein_foss_desktop_gis_overview.pdf) - Comprehensive comparison of GRASS 6.3.0, QGIS 0.9, uDig 1.1, gvSIG 1.1, SAGA 2.0.2, MapWindow 4.5, ILWIS 3.4, OpenJUMP 1.2D
- [Free and open source geographic information tools for landscape ecology (PDF)](http://www.geo.uzh.ch/~sstein/manuscripts/sstein_freegitools_ecoinf2009.pdf) - A second paper (using the same material) with the same software and ArcGIS thrown in
- [Evaluating open source GIS for libraries (PDF)](http://gothos.info/resource_files/fpd_libhitech_foss_gis_march2010.pdf) - Comparison of gvSIG 1.12, QGIS 1.0, uDig 1.1.1, OpenJUMP 1.2F, MapWindow 4.6.602, GRASS 6.4.0 (Via QGIS plugin)
- [Assessment of open source GIS software for water resources management in developing countries (PDF)](http://www.aquaknow.net/system/files/gis_software.pdf) - Started with just about every OS GIS ever conceived (over 30!) with a final detailed comparison of gvSIG, MapWindow, OpenJUMP and QGIS.

---

A bit meta, but someone's even written a paper on how to compare different GIS software;
[GIS software selection: a multi criteria decision making approach(PDF)](http://asoliman.kau.edu.sa/Files/195/Researches/58682_28929.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

As I answered on the question you are referring, I did a comparison for several FOSS Desktop GIS in 2008, with the purpose of finding the system that fits a set of criteria. I also developed a framework for such selections, based on other frameworks. The paper is available under a creative commons license at: http://code.atlefren.net/download/dl.php?id=10

Answer (score 3):

I co-wrote a [study on GRASS, gvSIG and QGIS communities](http://amaneiro.github.com/foss4g-desktop-analysis/), which may be an useful companion to other technical and economical studies. Actually, it compares the 3 reference desktop GIS applications as seen by OSGEO, but the [scripts to generate the statistics](https://github.com/amaneiro/foss4g-desktop-analysis) have been released as free software, so you should be able to tweak them to analyze other environments easily.