# Is there an comparison of the various mapping libraries for Android?

Tags: android, library

I am currently looking at the various libraries that I can use to show a map in my custom Android App. I have found several like Mapsforge, OSMDroid, ArcGIS runtime for Android, Google Maps for Android and so on. I'm sure that I am missing a few.

Is there a comparison chart somewhere about the differences in functionalities and pros and cons of each one?

If there isn't one, we could make this question community wiki, to serve alongside [Comparison of Open Source Desktop GIS Packages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23637/comparison-of-open-source-desktop-gis-packages) & [Comparison of JavaScript mapping libraries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries).

Comment: Are there any open source options that support multiple CRS (i.e. not just web mercator)?

Comment: @BradHards  As far as I know, only QGIS on android can do it, but it is still in a very early stage.

Comment: @BradHards: According to my latest research, the Nutiteq library can show maps in arbitrary CRS.

Comment: This Q&A is discussed in a [**Meta Q&A**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/should-we-mark-question-as-duplicate-when-adding-a-similar-question).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are the results of my brief research on this Issue:

1. **[ArcGIS runtime for Android](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-android/sdk)**. Seems to be oriented towards showing ArcGIS Server's Mapservices. It can show data in an offline mode, by storing tiles in the compact cache storage format, or by using tile packages.
2. **[OSMDroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid)** A component which can be used to show data from Open Street Maps when on-line, and can use tiles for off-line access. It is a raster based option, and you can use [Mobile Atlas creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to create tiles from pretty much any WMS service.
3. **[MapsForge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge)** An excellent library for rendering OSM data on the fly. It has a special optimized tile format, and it's rendering performance is quite good.
4. **[Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)** This is the default mapView in Android, and uses the data from Google Maps. While the Google map application itself can be used in offline mode, as far as I am aware, is not possible to use Google Data in the offline mode. However it is possible to show your own tiles in offline mode. [Here is an Excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles) example.
5. **[Nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/nutiteq-sdk/comparison/)** This is fully featured library that has many unique features like support for 3D, various OGC services, custom Map API's, offline routing and maps in any projection.
6. **[Mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk)** has recently released an Android SDK, which can be used for online and offline maps.
7. **[HERE](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/introduction.html)** has mobile sdks for Android and iOS, which can be used for online and offline maps.
8. **[CARTO](https://carto.com/engine/mobile/)** has mobile sdks for Android, iOS, and Windows Mobile 10, which can be used for online and offline maps.
9. **[Scout](https://developer.skobbler.com/)** has mobile sdks for Android and iOS, which can be used for online and offline maps.

Comment: TileMill MBtile could used for offline tiles , http://geospatialscott.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html

Comment: Nutiteq is free if you use it with OpenStreetMap, even for commercial applications. See https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Free-openstreetmap-license for the terms.

Comment: Early 2015: Is this answer still reasonably up-to-date?

Comment: @yochannah: I think so. I don't think any new library has come along for this. I have just updated the URLs today

Comment: Excellent solution based on Open Map Street (OMS) www.skobbler.com

Comment: Ntiteq retired their "free OSM license", so it might make sense to update the answer

Comment: Nutiteq is now part of CARTO